# trying to understand how html GET and res.redirect works in express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I am new to nodejs express et al..I am trying to understand why a res.redirect needs a GET to work..whereas a res.render don't. Here is the scenario. I have a login that uses passport for authentication with a database..good so far. After authentication depending on the type of user....the user is sent to a particular html page. If I just res.render the page it works fine....but if I res.redirect to the page I get a "Cannot GET..." error indicating I did't  have get('/page') block. Here is a sample code:

```
// get part request page
  router.get('/partpage', function(req,res) {
  res.render('partpage', {name: user.get("Name"),email:user.get("Email")});

});
// get dealer page
  router.get('/dealers', function(req,res) {
  res.render('dealers', {name: user.get("Name"),email:user.get("Email")});

});

.
.
.
router.post('/login',
 passport.authenticate( 'local',
    {sucessRedirect:'/',
     failureRedirect:'/users/login',
     failureFlash:true}),
 function(req,res)
 {
.
.
.

// After passport authentication.....

 if (user.get("Category")==="dealer")
     {
       res.redirect('/users/dealers?name='+username+'&email='+useremail);
     }
  else
     {
      res.redirect('/users/partpage?name='+username+'&email='+useremail);
     }
```

If I remove any one of the GET I get and error('Cannot GET...'). I don't understand why this is the case. More importantly I am passing parameters to the page...which one takes precedence? ...obviously something is wrong here! can anyone explain this for me? what is the correct way to to this?

The home page route is setup as follows:

in app.js

```
.
.
.
var routes = require('./routes/index');
.
.
.
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname,'views'));
app.set('view options', { layout:'layout.ejs' });
app.set('view engine','ejs');
.
.
.
app.use('/', routes);
```

Comment: On a successful login, you are redirecting to '/', do you have that route somewhere in your code?  If so, please add it to you question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

res.redirect is like something after web server accepts requrest, it behind the table force the browser to change the url, which means 302 http code. 
While res.render is web server just simply uses jade or ejs to render page, which means 200 http code.

In your case after user visiting `/login?Category=dealer`, his/her browser will be 302 to `/users/dealers?name=a&email=b`.
Then your server needs the router `router.get('/dealers', fn)` to show the page. Most importantly, user's browser url will be `/users/dealers?name=a&email=b`.

While if you directly use `res.render` in your authenticate callback, user's browser will show the rendered page, but the url is still `/login?Category=dealer`.

It's recommended to use redirect in your case. Otherwise if user presses 'F5' to refresh page, he/she actually is refresh url `/login?Category=dealer`, which will trigger your authenticate router and logic unnecessarily.

---

UPDATE:

The difference with render and redirect, (sorry I reply late, I wasn't able to visit stackoverflow these days due to the great wall)

***1***

user's browser issues http request to your server===>

your server get request, and uses res.render to output response, means your server returns 'http status 200' in response header, and 'html' in response body==>

user's browser gets '200 and html' response, then parses 'html' to view.

***2***

user's browser issues http request to your server===>

your server get request, and uses res.redirect, means your server returns 'http status 302 and new url' in response header, but no response returned.==>

user's browser gets '302 and new url' response, then relocate to the new url, which means user's browser iusses http request again, with this new url==>

your server get request, and uses res.render to output response, means your server returns 'http status 200' in response header, and 'html' in response body==>

user's browser gets '200 and html' response, then parses 'html' to view.

Comment: I realize thats what it is doing ...just don't see why. If I understand you correctly you are saying that the redirect(302) needs the GET to show the page after the redirect is issued? and in that case the parameters are not needed on the GET? ....so the GET should be: router.get('/dealers', function(req,res) {
  res.render('dealers')})

Comment: ....regardless of the parameters on the redirect? This is the part that's confusing me....having parameters on both calls.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you are saying that the redirect(302) needs the GET to show the page after the redirect is issued? ==========>
Right, redirect(302)  means user browser url will change, so of course you need to add router for the new url (in your case  it's /dealers?a=b&c=d )
===============================================
and in that case the parameters are not needed on the GET? =========>
it's up to your logic. If your `router.get('/dealers', fn)` needs the request parameters, you have to put them in the `res.redirect('/dealers?a=b&c=d')`

Comment: +1 for furthering my understanding of the subject but I don't think I got the answer I am looking for. From your answer, I didn't get a clear understanding as to why you would pass the params on the res.redirect and not the res.render.  Also, with EJS you can access the params from the res.render but not the res.redirect....can you elaborate some more to my specific area of concern. I need to pass and access the params using ejs, jquery or something similar.

Comment: Update in the answer, @MichaelE, sorry reply late, I wasn't able to visit stackoverflow due to the great wall.

Comment: +1 Got it...when the browser sees the 302 it creates GET to the url in the 302 which requires a GET route on the server...good. So the params on  the 302 would be processed by the GET route and if needed passed on by the res.render. Effectively I am passing the params to the browser twice...once in the 302 url, the browser pass it back to the server in the GET (302 url) and the server pass it back to the browser in the res.render. A circuitous route  but I suppose that's the spec.....Thanks for the assist.